# A portion of my webpage changes dynamically — how on Earth do I let screen readers know?

Tags: ajax, accessibility, screen-readers

Is it possible to dynamically update a portion of a webpage (for example: to display a list of errors from a form submission) and indicate to screen readers that they should skip to the updated portion?

Are full (non-Ajax) postbacks the only way to have accessible error messages?

**Edit (please see comments)**

To be clear, by "screen readers", I am referring to software that either speaks the text on the screen or converts that text to Braille.

Comment: You can dynamically update a portion of a web page using Ajax.

Comment: @Alpine Yes, that's what I'm doing. How do I let screen readers know that I've done so?

Comment: You can flash the content. For example if its a text message you can flash it in a different color for a second as soon as it is updated.

Comment: @Alpine I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this might help

[Making Ajax Work with Screen Readers](http://juicystudio.com/article/making-ajax-work-with-screen-readers.php)

---

Also See
[Implementing Screen Reader in Ajax](http://www.ajaxwith.com/Implementing-Screen-Reader-in-Ajax.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but did you see the update at the bottom of my question? By "screen readers", I don't mean "people reading the screen". I'm referring to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader

Changing text color won't help.

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.ajaxwith.com/Implementing-Screen-Reader-in-Ajax.html